# Comparing variables in Lists of two different types

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3D to create an RPG game similar to Final Fantasy and such. In c# of course.

For entities in the game, there are two separate classes: Character and Enemy.

For my battle code, I have two lists, one List called Party, and one List called Enemies.
I often need to compare and modify int values of ALL Characters and Enemies together, which was difficult to do because they are in separate lists. They have the same variables with the same names, e.g. (int Reflex, int Attack, int Strength, int Defense, etc. ) but they are a different type, so I don't know to do, for example, get the Character OR Enemy with the highest Reflex out of both lists for example.

My immediate inclination was to use them as derived classes, have both Character and Enemy inherit from a base class Entity with their overlapping variables contained in that. Then I could have one list of Entity in the battle to use. SO much easier, BUT damn Unity3D does not support polymorphism for its serialization process which all of my saving and loadings currently depends on.

I am hoping there is an easier answer for this; otherwise, I will have to painfully rewrite all of my saving and loading code, somehow, to not use Unity's serialization...

So basically, can I compare these variables things easily? And if so, how?

EDIT: Answered my own question

Comment: *"BUT damn Unity3D does not support polymorphism for its serialization process which all of my saving and loadings currently depends on."* I am not sure about this but please, include the code. Include the sample code of what you are done then people can help you with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might be kind of ridiculous so soon after having asked the question, but I just unexpectedly came across a very nice blog post describing the same problems that I was having:
http://www.archmagerises.com/news/2015/9/22/tips-on-game-world-state-data-serialization-in-unity-c

Following his example, I implemented sharpSerializer in my game. It works great, and I returned to my initially planned system of polymorphic classes.
Now I don't have to try to force my code to work around Unity's awful built-in serializer.

I wanted to post this because there don't seem to be many posts either on the Unity forums or here which address this issue, so anyone has the same problems as me can find a nice fix.

Comment: I do this with Unity's built in Json serializer and it works perfectly fine but if this works for you then go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Unity's built-in serializer could use a lot of work, but I've really only run into real-huge headaches while doing editor scripting. Like, I very much sympathize with [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/2e9vlg/unity_serialization_is_truly_fubar/) guy's rage. Run-time serialization is a bit different, it's a bit easier to work with, especially with the help of an external tool like [JsonDotNet](http://www.parentelement.com/assets/json_net_unity) for Unity, or I see you've mentioned elsewhere SharpSerializer. There's also [FullSerializer](https://github.com/jacobdufault/fullserializer) and it's asset store offshoot [FullInspector](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14913), which is intended specifically to help deal with those uniquely frustrating editor scripting headaches.

A couple things to note: Unity does support polymorphism for UnityEngine.Object derived classes, and this of course includes MonoBehaviour. As for custom classes, you can implement the ISerializationCallbackReciever interface if these classes have properties (such as Dictionary) which unity cannot by default serialize. Otherwise you just add the [Serializeable] tag to the class to let unity know that you want that data to be saved. There are a few other caveats you should familiarize yourself with, see : https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/24/serialization-in-unity/

Using your use case as an example, the usual structure might look something like this:

```
[Serializeable]
public Class ActorProperties{

    public int CurrentHealth;
    public int MaxHealth;
    public int Range;

}


public Class Actor : MonoBehaviour{
    [SerializeField] protected ActorProperties _actorProperties
    public ActorProperties ActorProperties{
        get{ return _actorProperties;}
        set{_actorProperties = value;}
    }
}

public Class Character : Actor{
    // Character specific code
}

public Class Enemy : Actor{
    // Enemy specific Code
}

public Class GameManager : MonoBehaviour{
    private List<Actor> enemies;
    private List<Actor> characters;

    public List<Actor> AllActors{
        get{ 
            List<Actor> returnList = new List<Actor>(characters);
            returnList.AddRange(enemies);
            return returnList;
        }
    }


   public Actor GetActorWithHealth(float healthCheck){
       Actor actor = AllActors.Find(x => x.ActorProperties.CurrentHealth == healthCheck);
       return actor;
   }
}
```

Aside from Non-Serialized DataTypes, the example below illustrates most common instances when custom serialization is needed.

```
// Even though Properties is marked as Serializeable, it's 'data' property 
// won't get serialized if we're serializing a reference to an ActorProperties.
// No native support for polymorphic serialization of custom classes.
[Serializable] 
public class Properties{
    public float data;
}

[Serializeable]
public class ActorProperties : Properties{

    // Here we have a recursion problem because Unity cannot serialize 
    // null values for custom classes. Unity will try to serialize this ActorProperties field, which in turn starts the serialization over again,
    // with an iteration depth of 7. Killer if it were a List<ActorProperties> .
    public ActorProperties EnemyProperties; 
    public int CurrentHealth;
    public int MaxHealth;
    public int Range;

    // Since Unity treats custom classes like structs, the following field wont be serialized 
    // as a pointer to an existing object, but as a unique instance of it's class.
    public CustomClass SharedReference;

}
```

Serialization solutions like Json.NET for Unity et. al. go a long way towards making the serialization process easier, but regardless of what solution you use, it's extremely important to pay attention to precisely how your data is going to be serialized.

Personally I would recommend Json.Net for Unity, but the only other assets I've had some experience with is FullSerializer and FullInspector. I've not used SharpSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not abstract away the data for Characters and Enemies by using a Plain Old C# class with an ID field? (maybe called something like "CreatureData" "ActorData" or "CharacterData"). Each instance of this abstract class could then reference this new ID field that is contained within both Characters and Enemies.

Instances of the new C# class could then be stored in another collection of some kind like a dictionary or a list and easily iterated through later.

Unless I'm mistaken, as long as you make this new class serialize-able, Unity should still be able to handle it.

Comment: That was an option but would take a lot of time and effort because of the way everything was nested (only one object was saved, Game, which contained arrays of other Objects which were all custom classes, and those custom classes contained other custom classes, custom structs, etc)

edit: but I answered my own question below so I feel pretty satisfied.